# UITableViewCell subclass reload subview on redisplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` populated with cells that belong to the `RightArrowTableViewCell` class which subclasses `UITableViewCell`. The subclassed cell contains an accesory-like view for an arrow icon (`arrowDecoratorView`). When a main category is selected the arrow icon is rotated downwards to reveal a list of sub categories in the same table view.

When, however, the tableview is scrolled and the main category cell is "moved out of view", things do not go that well. As soon as the main category cell is moved back in sight, the arrow icon resumes its initial horizontal position.

To fix this I have added a flag to the `RightArrowTableViewCell` class to check whether the cell is expanded or not. Then in the `tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:` method I do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    RightArrowTableViewCell *arrowCell = (RightArrowTableViewCell *)cell;
    if (arrowCell.iconExpanded) {
        [arrowCell updateIconStatus];
    }
}
```

The `updateIconStatus` goes like this:

```
- (void)updateIconStatus{
    self.arrowDecoratorView.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2.5);
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

The above solution seems to work but not for long. After 3-4 scrolls that hide/reveal the main category cell in succession, the arrow icon resumes its original horizontal position.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and the flag cant be a property of your subclassed UITableViewCell cause the cells are being reused, so the propery should belong to the data structure from which you trie to populate the table. Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CustomDataClass *data = [_arData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(data.expand){
        [cell ShowArrowInThisPos];
    }
    else{
        [cell ShowArrowInThatPos];
    }
    ... some code

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are probably right about the property. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I can't believe I was trying to save a property inside a UITableViewCell that is meant to be reused...

Answer (score 0):

You could try restoring the `transform` of the `arrowDecoratorView` in `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, that is make the rotation in the other direction `-M_PI * 2.5`. However, this could still get out of sync at some point, I guess.

Comment: Thanks but the transform is taking place every time. The update is not always showing up.

Comment: Could you try updating the icon status in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:?

Comment: That was a good idea. I have overriden prepareForReuse in the UITableViewCell subclass as follows: - (void)prepareForReuse{
    if (self.iconExpanded) {
        [self updateIconStatus];
    }
} but the issue persists.

Comment: The documentation about the prepareForReuse method states that when overriding you should always invoke the superclass implementation, but I doubt that this will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you post a working example somewhere so we could see the behavior you are describing? It will be easier for anyone to make a suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56894/discussion-between-don-miguel-and-f1ank3r).